# Laravel custom validation with rule object: Access other fields or validator

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using the rule object from Laravel 8

```
artisan make:rule RequireBetweenOf
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects

**How do I access other fields or the validator?**

I need to check other data in the validator.

I know how it works for for `Validator::extend()` as 4. parameter but that does not work for `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule`. I have also seen that there is a answer using `request()`. But that is a hack, because validator data and request might not be the same. There might be no request at all.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidatorAwareRule;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\DataAwareRule;

class RequireBetweenOf implements Rule, DataAwareRule, ValidatorAwareRule
```

---

I found the password rule is using the validator: `\Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password::setValidator`.
Digging deeper this is used here: `\Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUsingCustomRule`.

Key are those two interfaces: `\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidatorAwareRule` and `\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\DataAwareRule`